# Gerar image causa erro imagettftext invalid font filename - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou trabalhando em um projeto wordpress, e preciso gerar uma imagem dinamicamente, utilizando a função imagecreatefromjpeg() do PHP além da função imagettftext() para adicionar textos personalizados na imagem, com fontes da minha escolha.

O Script que desenvolvi funciona perfeitamente, porém quando tento utilizá-lo dentro da página do wordpress não consigo buscar a fonte.

Exemplo de código (funciona):

```
<?php

/*---------------------------------------*/
// Header informando que é uma imagem JPEG
header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );

// Carregar imagem já existente no servidor
$imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg( "cupomFinal.jpg" );    
$cor = imagecolorallocate($imagem, 119, 119, 119);
$corTitle = imagecolorallocate($imagem, 163, 72, 177);

// Texto que será escrito na imagem
$nome = "Cliente: Vinicius Ribeiro";
$email = "Email: teste@teste.com.br";
$contato = "Contato: 31-0000-0000";
$codigo = "Código:";
$codigoDesconto = "00000-00-000-2015";

$font = 'RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf';
$fontCodigo = 'impact.ttf';

// INSERE OS TEXTOS NA IMAGEM COM AS FONTES ESCOLHIDAS
imagettftext($imagem, 16, 0, 390, 140, $cor, $font, $nome);
imagettftext($imagem, 13, 0, 390, 170, $cor, $font, $email);
imagettftext($imagem, 13, 0, 390, 200, $cor, $font, $contato);
imagettftext($imagem, 12, 0, 50, 170, $corTitle, $fontCodigo, $codigo);
imagettftext($imagem, 18, 0, 50, 200, $corTitle, $fontCodigo, $codigoDesconto);


// eEnvia a imagem para o borwser ou arquivo
imagejpeg( $imagem, NULL, 90);
imagedestroy($imagem);
?>
```

O código acima foi testado em separado e funcionou perfeitamente, porém quando tento implementar dentro do wordpress, a fonte nunca é encontrada!

Como o comando "header" indica que a página será uma imagem, basta comentar para visualizar os erros. Sendo assim visualizei o seguinte retorno:

[image: Erro apresentado. Caminho da fonte.]

Já tentei utilizar vários caminhos para a fonte e todos sem sucesso.

Em algumas tentativas utilizei a função imagestring() que também escreve na imagem, porém sem a fonte personalizada, e o script funcionou perfeitamente com a sintaxe abaixo:

```
imagestring($imagem, 5, 390, 170,  $email, $cor);
```

Porém seria é de extrema importância que eu utilize a fonte personalizada.

Agradeço desde já o auxílio.

Abraço.

Comment: De que forma você está fazendo a importação da fonte?

Comment: @JoerisonSilva a fonte é adicionada na pasta do projeto, e chamada através das variáveis $font e $fontCodigo.

Comment: Tentando novas possibilidades e com a ajuda dessa pergunta:

(http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&u=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489573/invalid-font-filename-imagettfbox&usg=ALkJrhikDFhAmzcOgWKSt-YYR3OCH0SQRg)

Consegui resolver o  problema.
Utilizei o caminho local dentro da variável que busca a fonte, dessa forma:

C:\wamp\www\projeto\site\wp-content\\themes\projeto\impact.ttf"

Obrigado a todos.